# What's the next number? You may need some help

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

What's the next number in the following sequence?

> 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 18, 21, 23, 28, 31, ___, ...

Hints will be released gradually - the first one is in the title.

Hint #2:

> Depending on where you live, you may have never seen these numbers.

Additionally:

> Never seeing these numbers is in fact an advantage, *not* a disadvantage.

Hint #3:

> No math is involved (except for counting).

Hint #4:

> The human brain may not be enough. Ask Google or Wikipedia for help.

Final Hint:

> How do you search using Google for a sequence that you've never seen, or even has never existed? Google is not powerful enough to find something non-existent for you. You need to search for something else.

Comment: From Hint 2: Does this mean that someone in a different geographical location to you would be unable to solve this 'with ease'?

Comment: No, I believe it shouldn't matter. You may need the same kind of "help" anyway.

Comment: Maybe a hint?..

Comment: @nicael updated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is:

> 32

Search Google for the remaining numbers in the sequence:

> https://goo.gl/oTOCNA

Which gives:

> The labels of [Interstate highways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_Highway_System). With both sequences, one gets 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...

Image added:

> [image: List of numbers used in main US Interstate Highways]

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to be working, just so you know.

Answer (score 1):

> $32$.

Why?

> When put into a $2$ by $n$ field, a pattern is formed. It's shown in the green section. The red parts are the next sections of the sequence. Black spots are numbers in the sequence. This is read as $1$ at the top, $2$ at the bottom, $3$ on the top and one to the right and so on. [image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite get it... :P This doesn't seem to work well with the hints.

Comment: Right answer, wrong method, hah. It's worth noting your pattern only starts quite a few numbers in...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realize it could be weird, but still -

> $33$

The assumptions are

> Every ten numbers begin with ones which have $1$ and $3$ as the last digit, the further numbers differ
> $1,3,6,7,9$
> $1,3,4,8$
> $1,3,8$
> $1,?$ 
> Hence, it would look that the next number should end with $3$

Comment: It's not that complicated :)

Comment: @Pig You mean what, the rule is way easier?

Comment: It does not involve any complicated mathematical analysis.

Comment: @Pig Huh, ok then.

Comment: Make sure you've seen those updated hints.

Comment: @Pig yep, seen them :)